# Inclusion-Exclusion principle in a Zoo

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a Zoo, there are $6$ Bengal white tigers and $6$ Bengal royal tigers. Out of these tigers, $5$ are males and $10$ are either Bengal royal tigers or males. Find the number of female Bengal white tigers in the Zoo.

MY EFFORT:-
No. Of white tiger $n(w) = 6$
No. Of royal tiger $n(R) = 6$
Total no. Of tiger $n(T) = 12$
No. Of male tiger $n(M) =5$
No. Of royal or male tiger $n(R \cup M) = 10$
No. Of female and white tiger $n(F \cap W) =$ ?

If I use formula
$n(A \cup B) = n(A) + n(B) – n(A \cap B)$
I can't able to find answer
Pls help me!

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @5xum I hope you solve this question
Thanks for help

Comment: Using the formula above (Inclusion-Exclusion) we have n(R ∪ M) = n(R) + n(M) – n(R ∩ M)  from which: 10=6+5-n(R ∩ M) and we have that the number of Bengal royal male=1. Thus, the remaining 5 Bengal royal are females.

Comment: If the overall number of tigers is 12 and 5 are males, we have 7 females. O these 7, 5 are Bengal royal; thus, 2 are Bengal white.

Comment: 12 - 10 = 2....

Comment: Within your set of $12$ tigers, consider set complements: if $R^C = W$ and $M^C = F$, then $(R\cup M)^C = R^C\cap M^C = F\cap W$ by De Morgan's law.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: Once again thank you